# AngularJS comparator - how to get it work

Tags: angularjs, comparator

I have written this jsfiddle to test AngularJS comparator but the comparator does not work:

[my jsFiddle Comparator](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11220/)

It seems that my comparator function wiggleSort will not be invoked:

```
<span data-ng-repeat="myItem in myArray | orderBy:'start':false:wiggleSort"
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to sort items by their widdleTime. What you're doing now is to extract the start time of each item, and then compare those strings by calling widdleSort on these strings, although widdleSort expects items as argument.

All you need is

```
$scope.wiggleTime = function(item) {
    var t = 60 * parseInt(item.start.substr(0, 2), 10) + parseInt(item.start.substr(3), 10);
    return (t >= 720) ? 2160 - t : t;
}
```

and

```
orderBy:wiggleTime
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/835tsfut/